# Install Ubuntu on MacBook Pro 2006 running OS X 10.4.11

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, mac

I have a early 2006 MacBook Pro core duo 2.0 ghz with 2GB Ram running OS X Tiger 10.4.11
I have tried both the Usb and DVD boot up with Ubunto 16.4 and 18 and the machine never recognises the USB or DVD at start up when I boot up holding the option key, only the HD installed.
Any help guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks and stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully created a bootable USB for a Mac Mini 2,1 (2007) just last week. I've been searching and trying for a while. What I've discovered is that most Linux distributions don't have an EFI implementation on their ISOs that satisfies those old Macs. I'll write a tutorial sometime in the next few weeks (I still want to find another working ISO, other than the one I've used), but it is actually quite simple.

In my findings you just need an extra folder to be included on the flash drive, which is 'efi/boot/', and inside that folder you'll need a few files. As I'm not an expert, what I did was copy/paste from another working flash drive that I created with a distro that worked just fine to be bootable form that Mac Mini. So here you go:

1. Download a version of [GeexBox][1], which is a simple Linux distro that only runs a media center. You'll only need the flash drive created with this. Or better yet, if you have any computer with a Linux OS, you may be able to just mount the ISO (just as a Mac would mount a DMG), and copy the files from there.
2. So either create a flash drive with the previous ISO, or mount the ISO. Open the flash drive (or the mounted ISO) and copy the whole 'efi' folder anywhere on your computer. It will be 'efi/boot' and inside boot you'll find 3 files.
3. Go ahead and create the USB flash drive with any distro you prefer.
4. Now comes the only tricky part. Most Linux distros, such as Ubuntu use Grub as a bootloader, and it uses a menu to display the OS boot options for you. Usually, the configuration for grub is in a file with '.cfg' extension. The one I was using last week was Ubuntu 14.04, so I opened the flash drive created with this iso and found a 'boot/grub' folder and a 'loopback.cfg' inside. Since I also have a copy of the Ubuntu 18.04 here, I just looked and it has the same folder, but with both 'grub.cfg' and 'loopback.cfg' there. I guess either will work (and someone with more expertise might correct me later saying which one is better). Open this file in a text editor and what you'll really need are the lines that begin with `menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing"`.

   Go ahead and copy from that line until the end. In the Ubuntu 18.04 ISO, the loopback.cfg file seems to be all you need, since it only has those lines (with a few differences from the other file).
5. Go back to the folder that you've copied from GeexBox ISO/pen, and inside 'efi/boot' you'll see 'grub.cfg'. At this point, this configuration text file makes grub point to Geexbox, because you took it from there. Open it on a text editor, and replace the lines that start with `menuentry "Try...` with the ones you just copied from the '.cfg' file of your distro.
6. Now be careful. The iso that I used, Ubuntu 14.04, didn't have that 'efi/boot' folder, so I just copied the whole thing to the root of the flash drive. But as I just saw, Ubuntu 18.04 already has those folders, so if your distro's ISO already has 'efi/boot' on its root, just copy the files inside there. If it doesn't have 'efi/boot', copy the whole folders+files to the root. I just did drag'n'drop. It's as simple as that.

   There should be 3 files inside 'efi/boot' on your flash drive now:

   - 8x13.pf2
   - bootia32.efi
   - grub.cfg

   I guess that those old Macs used an implementation of EFI that was 32-bit (hence this 'bootia32.efi' there). Modern EFI uses 64-bit (you'll find a *bootx64.efi* inside the same folder on Ubuntu 18.04 for example).

That should work. Try it out and let us know. Good luck!